# Cannot get http-server to run with nodejs command line from angular-seed github project

Tags: node.js, angularjs, httpserver

I am attempting to get a better understanding of nodejs so that I can get an IntelliJ plugin working.

I have installed NodeJS on my Windows 7 machine and verified that it works from the command line (node, then did a 2+2 it answered 4).

I then git cloned the AngularJS Seed project (https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) and proceeded to get that running (npm install, npm start) and all was good.

But then I tried using node to directly kick off the http-server module with the following command line from the AngularJS source directory.

```
node node_modules\.bin\http-server -a localhost -p 8000
```

and

```
node node_modules\.bin\http-server.cmd -a localhost -p 8000
```

Both commands give me the following error -

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3`

Am I missing something easy here since I am new to NodeJS or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run http-server directly, you should install it globally:

```
npm install http-server -g
```

Then you can run the following:

```
http-server -a localhost -p 8000
```

Comment: You could explain what the error message means, and how your solution solves that...

Comment: I'm also trying to use the NodeJS plugin in IntelliJ (I should have added that, appologies) which calls Node to do things.  As I said, npm start does work and that wasn't my question.  My question was why when I try it with Node directly does it fail, because this is how the NodeJS plugin in IntelliJ works.

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
Working dir: /path/to/your/package.json

JavaScript file: /path/to/global/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js

Application parameters: run start
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576950/create-webstorm-run-configurations-from-package-json-scripts-section)