# Create WebStorm run configurations from package.json "scripts" section

Tags: node.js, configuration, npm, webstorm, package.json

In my `package.json` file, I have the following "scripts" configuration.

```
...
"scripts": {
    "start": "watchify -o lib/index.js -v -d .",
    "build": "browserify . | uglifyjs -cm > lib/index.js",
    "test": "jest"
}
...
```

This allows me to run `npm start`, `npm build` and `npm test` from the command line.

This is great! But ideally, I would like to be able to run those tasks from within WebStorm using run configurations, due to how convenient the interface is. I have not been able to figure out how to do this.

Is there a way to create my own custom run configurations or automatically generate them from my `package.json`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

you can use Node.js Run configuration for this. For example, for `'npm start'`:

```
Working dir: /path/to/your/package.json

JavaScript file: /path/to/global/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js

Application parameters: run start
```

To find the global node_modules path from the command line use "npm root -g".

There is no way to auto-create run configurations from files. And the only way to create your own run configuration is developing a plugin - see http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Run+Configurations

**Update**: since 2016.x, WebStorm provides a special run configuration - [npm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.3/run-debug-configuration-npm.html) - for running/debugging NPM scripts. It can be created manually via **Edit configurations...** dialog, or auto-added by selecting the script in [NPM tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.3/npm-tool-window.html) (can be opened from `package.json` right-click menu).

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.3/running-npm-scripts.html

Comment: This works, but you won't be able to debug from within Webstorm

Comment: Since this took a while to find. On mac `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js` is where you will find the that js file.

Comment: If you want to debug check this out: http://pavelpolyakov.com/2016/05/01/webstorm-npm-tasks-debug/

Answer (score 2):

WebStorm and IntelliJ 2016 included support for NPM scripts as part of the NodeJS plugin.

> Scripts are launched in four ways:
>
> - From a tree of scripts in the dedicated [NPM Tool Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/npm-tool-window.html). The tool window opens when you invoke *npm* by choosing *Show npm Scripts* on the context menu of a `package.json` in the *Project* tool window or of a `package.json` opened in the editor.
> - According to a dedicated run configuration, see [Run/Debug Configuration: NPM](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/run-debug-configuration-npm.html).
> - Automatically, as a start-up task.
> - As a before-launch task, from another run configuration.

For more details check out [their documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/running-npm-scripts.html).