# Running AngularJS/NodeJS project from WebStorm. Getting error running http-server from Run Configurations

Tags: angularjs, node.js, webstorm

I cloned the seed angular project from git in Web Storm and have the following content in `/node_modules/.bin/http-server`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
basedir=`dirname "$0"`

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/../http-server/bin/http-server" "$@"
  ret=$?
else
  node  "$basedir/../http-server/bin/http-server" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```

I created following run configuration -

[image]

```
..\..Angular\node_modules\.bin\http-server:2
basedir=`dirname "$0"`
        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

The package.json contains the following under scripts tag-

```
"prestart": "npm install",
    "start": "http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1",
```

If I do `npm start` on command line, server launches successfully. I am just wondering what causes this error when I am trying to launch it through run config in IDE.

I also installed `shelljs` under project directory guessing that parsing `hhtp-server` may be the problem. No luck.

Any idea??

Comment: Your `/node_modules/.bin/http-server` file is **1)** not JavaScript file (you are trying to use it in that field in Run/Debug configuration) **2)** it's a **bash shell script** which meant to be run on Linux/Mac and not on your Windows.

Comment: Agree. Just wondering as what could be the possible way to invoke the server in windows other than command line. Also, how come it runs in command prompt then? The same bash shell script I mean, invoked by npm start.

Comment: Why do you think the same file is actually executed? It's most likely either actual JS file or windows-specific version (e.g. `*.cmd`). I only wanted to comment on that part -- cannot help further as I'm not NodeJS person myself, at all.

Comment: Your pointer is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks LazyOne. Your input was helpful and I got the pointer in the right direction and could resolve it from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576950/create-webstorm-run-configurations-from-package-json-scripts-section)